ArgoCD PostSync - How to know which application is synced
in ArgoCD i have multiple applications, I want to configure a common PostSync hook to all of them. The purpose of the postsync is to notify someone that which application is synced. How can I know which application is synced when the common postsync is triggered?
I created a job with annotation "argocd.argoproj.io/hook: PostSync", in the job it will run a script to send out a message saying that application is synced. But how to set a variable automatically that telling which application is just synced.

You should be able to use Build environment variables: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/build-environment/
